# Model mesh overlapping while animating in Unity but not in Blender

Tags: unity, animation, blender

I made an FPS model in blender and created reload animation when I imported that model in Unity I saw that while the magazine ejecting from the rifle it overlapped some of the gun parts. Then I went back to the blender and changed some keyframes and positions in the blender but in Unity, it showed me the same problem. I tried many times it looks fine in the blender but in the Unity, it has the same problem.

[image: Unity]

[image: Blender]

Comment: have you tried reimporting the model? have set the animation type in the "animation" tab import settings? Have you set your avatar correctly? I can't really see what's the difference between the two images; Could you make it more evident please?

Comment: @GabrieleVierti I've updated my images. I red circled the portion which is different in blender and unity. The magazine part coming out from the magazine holder in unity, but it looks normal in the blender as I want. I've imported the model many times but it has the same problem

Comment: off the key-frame reduction in animation.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan what does keyframe reduction mean, could you explain a bit.